# Should the views count in the sidebar be formatted?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, views

This is something that I've only just started noticing on some older SO questions that I've bookmarked at some point in history with a code-snippet that I may use once at the beginning of every new project.

Typically on the sidebar, the user will see some useful information. How long ago the question was asked is displayed clearly and comprehensibly, as well as when the question was last active, allowing him/her to question the relevance of the question to the specific problem that they are coming across at the moment.

*However*. The 'viewed' count is considerably less easy to read and, as shown in the below example, may take slightly longer to interpret because it is almost entirely unformatted.

**89,583 times** is significantly easier to read than **89583 times**.

[image: Typical Sidebar]

Furthermore, on the right of the *[High Voted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)* page, the number of questions is region formatted, and therefore, for the sake of consistency, I emphasise the following proposition.

[image: High Voted Questions count]

I propose that the 'viewed' count should be formatted based on locale i.e. '89,583' for the UK, and '89.583' or '89 583' for Europe etc...

Comment: I would prefer following the SI guidelines and putting spaces there rather than punctuation.

Comment: @Louis I'd prefer punctuation as it's what people would be more used to when reading in their native language, however it's a personal preference I suppose. As long as we can introduce a higher level of readability, I will have achieved my aim!

Comment: *I'd prefer punctuation as it's what people would be more used to when reading in their native language* In French groups of 3 numbers are separated by spaces.

Comment: So that space will act as the punctuation.

Comment: (I know this will affect how all numbers are formatted on SO but ) How about using locale formatting for thousand separator?

Comment: The fact this is still an issue makes me so very very sad.

Comment: @IanKemp how do we GTM?

Answer (score 7):

Sidebar commas coming to you live... in the next production build.

Not taking locale into account at the moment since we don't pretty much anywhere else as far as I know, and consistency wins for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for going with commas and not periods or spaces. Periods always confuse me as a thousand separator

Comment: @NickA: And commas confuse the 90% of people that don’t have English as a native language. It’s nice, being able to look at the world and think it’s all like back home, no?